# Dockerize ubuntu with docker for windows

Tags: python, docker, flask

I've create

- Dockerfile
- app.py
- requirements.txt

here my code

**app.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Welcome!"

@app.route('/how are you')
def hello():
    return 'I am good, how about you?'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
 Flask
```

**Dockerfile**

```
 FROM ubuntu:latest
 RUN apt-get update -y
 RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
 COPY . /app
 WORKDIR /app
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
 CMD ["app.py"]
```

Then i build the image

```
docker build . -t dede-flask:latest
```

But i got an error with run script

1. first i've try with this code

```
  docker run dede-flask:latest
```

i got error

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 14, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 944, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1007, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 176, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

2. i've too try with this code

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 dede-flask:latest
```

i got an error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint friendly_bhaskara (990535df1272811a3991c8a11e06476267e027484b850c244ca195e9d5b8a220): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:5000:tcp:172.17.0.2:5000: input/output error.
```

Comment: try following some of the leads in here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2722

Comment: You can use official python docker image. This would be more safe